# Generating data for a Java game using a second Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I am creating a voxel game in Java. Currently, I am using perlin noise to generate data for 3d chunks (16x16x16 short arrays) which are contained in a HashMap. This all works correctly. When the player moves, I want to render the chunks near the player (right now, 5 chunks in any direction). If a chunk does not exist, it should generate it.

The problem is that it takes about half a second to generate a chunk so when the player moves out of the generated area, the game loop freezes for a couple seconds while it generates the necessary chunks and then resumes.

I am using lwjgl for OpenGL and my game loop looks something like this:

```
while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){
    update(); //my update method
    render(); //my render method
    Display.update(); //refresh the screen
    Display.sync(60); //sync to 60 fps
}
```

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use a second thread to generate data while updating and rendering but I could not figure out how to do it without freezing the game loop. I think there should be a way to queue chunks to generate in a second thread and then run that thread in short bursts but I have little to no experience with multithreading in Java so any help with that would be appreciated.

Comment: Your loop is rather irrelevant here. What have you tried in terms of multi-threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem using only one thread. I created a TaskManager which was responsible for holding an arraylist of tasks to be done. So every time I needed to generate a chunk, I would pass a task object that contained information to actually perform the task. Then, every update, I would call TaskManager.next() which would perform the next task.

Now, instead of generating 49 new chunks in one update which froze the framerate, it generates one chunk per update until they are all generated.

Comment: Doesn't that lead to a delayed display of the chunks?

Comment: Yes, if the player is close enough to see the chunks, it will appear as if they render one by one. However, if the chunks are generated far enough away from the player so the player can't see them, there is no delayed display.

Answer (score 0):

If the player can see the five chunks around him, you can maybe generate the chunks six rows away before he enters one direction. This way you have done the work early enough and you can display the chunks directly.
This task of generating the chunks you can do in a separate thread. It doesn't have to be called in the game-loop. You have to invoke the generater-thread before entering the game-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a background thread that's notified when the player moves, then pregenerates chunks adjacent to the where the player moved. It's backed by a priority queue so that backlogs of never-visited cells aren't at the top of the queue, and old queue entries are removed once they're a certain distance from the player.

The key to leveraging threading is that you're generating the chunks *before* the player moves there, and taking down time in movements to generate chunks, and possibly unneeded chunks.

And the big caveat: if you offload all generation to that thread, you're going to need to use Futures so you always get back a generated chunk.